# Standard Coordinates and Covectors for Differential Forms

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms

I've started reading Bott and Tu's text *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* and I think my understanding is quite poor when it comes to the standard coordinates and covectors. Let me explain my understanding and if you could confirm/clarify it that would be great.

Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for the moment. Then Bott and Tu defines $y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{n}$ as the **standard coordinates** on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I take this to mean that the $y_{i}$ are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. However on page 19, Bott and Tu define a pullback map $f^{*}:\Omega^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to \Omega^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ (where $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is smooth, $\Omega^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is the space of $0$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and similarly for $\mathbb{R}^{m}$) defined by

$$f^{*}(g) = g \circ f.$$

This definition is then extended to a map on all forms such that it commutes with the exterior derivative $d$ and the extended map $f^{*}$ is given by

$$f^{*}(\sum g_{I}dy_{{i_{1}}} \cdots dy_{i_{q}}) = \sum(g_{I} \circ f)df_{{i_{1}}} \cdots df_{i_{q}}.$$

where $f_{i} = y_{i} \circ f$ and the $y_{i}$ are the standard coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But if the standard coordinates are basis vectors then how is $y_{i}$ even defined as a function? Moreover, we already have standard coordinates $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}$ for $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ (this is implicit in the defintion above) so how are the $f_{i}$ standard coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^{m}$? Also, aren't the covectors $dx_{i}$ and $df_{i}$ different?

Now for covectors. From sources other than Bott and Tu, I understand that the covectors $dy_{i}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are linear functionals from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $dy_{i}$ sends a vector to its $i$-th coordinate. Is this the correct understanding or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am comparing the notation used in Bott and Tu to that used in John M. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", since they are similar (if you have access to a copy of Lee's book, check out page 4-5).

For now consider a general $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ with a chart $(U,\varphi)$, where $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The smooth map $\varphi$ is the (local) coordinate map, and the component functions $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ of $\varphi$ are defined by $\varphi(p) = (x_{1}(p),\ldots, x_{n}(p))$. Despite looking straight-forward so far I want to apply this to an example (stereographic projection). Let $U = S^{2} - \{(0,0,1)\}$ be the sphere without the North pole, then $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is given by
$$
\varphi(x,y,z) = \bigg(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z}\bigg).
$$
So now here, $p = (x,y,z)$ and $x_{1}(x,y,z) = x/(1-z)$, and similarly $x_{2}(x,y,z) = y/(1-z)$.

The reason why I gave an example first is because when the manifold is as simple as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, what is actually going on is much more subtle since unlike with a more general manifold $M$, there is actually just one chart, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ itself. And the coordinate map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is in fact just  the identity map.

As for $f_{j} = y_{j} \circ f$, here $y_{j}$ just represents the $j$-th element of the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e. it ends up being the projection onto the $j$-th factor:
$$
y_{j} \circ f(p) = y_{j}( f_{1}(p),\ldots, f_{n}(p)) = f_{j}(p),
$$
so $f_{j} = y_{j} \circ f$. Please let me know if anything is unclear or if I missed anything.

Comment: So we have an atlas $\{(\mathbb{R}^{n},\text{id})\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $\text{id}$ is the identity. Then the standard coordinate $y_{i}$ is the $i$th component of $\text{id}$. So the $y_{i}$ are functions not vectors. Then what are the $dy_{i}$? Also, isn't there an issue if I have some $q$-form on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $dx_{1},dx_{2},\ldots,dx_{m}$ as my covectors and another $q$-form with $df_{1},df_{2},\ldots,df_{m}$ as my covectors? We are fine if there is a diffeomorphism between the $x_{i}$ and $f_{i}$ (page 20) but this isn't always the case if $f$ is just smooth.

Comment: Each $y_{j}: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function yes, and then $dy_{j}$ is the differential of $y_{j}$, and is dual to the basis vector $\partial/\partial y_{j}$ considered pointwise (I highly recommend looking at Tu's 'An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds', page 33, too if this looks unfamiliar). For the second question, the $dx_{j}$ and $df_{j}$ are just different bases to the cotangent space, related to each other by the dual of the differential. So the differential of $f$ is bijective thus $f$ is a diffeomorphism by the IFT.